# Putty Connect Issues

Tags: ssh, connection, putty, virtualenv

I am trying to ssh into a virtual machine using putty. The VM has my public key and I am able to connect to the VM when I am using one internet connection but when I go to another location the connection times out and I cannot connect.

I believe this is an AWS EC2 server but do not have that information on my side.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is this VM? Are you connecting to an Amazon EC2 instance? Or is this something on a local network? Could you [edit] your question to include a little bit of detail about the network aspect? This will make it easier to offer possible solutions.

Comment: Read about routing.

Comment: "connection times out" suggests a networking problem, not an authentication problem.